# Why is crashReporter undefined in Electron?

Tags: javascript, electron

I recently upgraded to Electron version 1.6.11 and now when I run my `npm start` command, I get the following error:

[image]

The top of my `main.js` file looks like this:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain, crashReporter} = require('electron');
const path = require('path');

crashReporter.start({
    productName: 'MyCo',
    companyName: 'MyCo, Inc.',
    submitURL: 'https://myco.co/fake-url-to-submit',
    uploadToServer: true
});

app.on('window-all-closed', function() {
  if (process.platform != 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});
```

Here are the contents of my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "productName": "MyApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "main.js",
  "repository": "https://github.com/zackshapiro/myApp",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.7.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.17.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "electron": "^1.6.11",
    "electron-packager": "^8.7.1",
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.1.3",
    "eslint": "^3.13.1",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.9.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.10.1",
    "node-libs-browser": "^1.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.2.0",
    "sass-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "webpack": "^2.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "./node_modules/electron-prebuilt/dist/Electron.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron .",
    "watch": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server",
    "electron-rebuild": "./node_modules/.bin/electron-rebuild"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.22.0",
    "electron-context-menu": "^0.8.0",
    "electron-prebuilt": "^0.37.2",
    "gl-react": "^2.2.9",
    "gl-react-hue-rotate": "^1.1.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "rc-slider": "^6.1.0",
    "react": "15.4.2",
    "react-dnd": "^2.2.4",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^2.2.4",
    "react-dom": "15.4.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.2",
    "react-router": "^4.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
    "react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.6",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-saga": "^0.14.3",
    "tinycolor2": "^1.4.1"
  }
}
```

How do I fix this and get `crashReporter` working?

Comment: Can we see your package.json?

Comment: Adding it now. 1 sec

Comment: this github issue seems relavent. https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/7475
Seems the two things to check are that its being called with `electron` not not `node` and that `main,js` is only being called one time

Comment: Have you tried changing your `start` script to `./node_modules/.bin/electron .`?

Comment: That did the trick. Weird

Comment: Thanks @AndrewLi. Wanna post an answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `start` script is wrong -- you're trying to use `electron-prebuilt` which is outdated, but you probably forgot to uninstall it from your computer so it still works. It's currently in your `devDependencies` but it's been deprecated and hasn't been supported since 2016. Remove it with:

```
npm uninstall --save-dev electron-prebuilt
```

`electron-prebuilt` does not come with `crashReporter` thus it is undefined when you try to import it.

You should be using the latest `electron` you've installed which comes with `crashReporter`. To do this, change the script to (if you've installed it locally):

```
"start": "./node_modules/.bin/electron ."
```

This will use `electron` instead of `electron-prebuilt` and it should work fine.

Comment: Should I remove `electron-prebuilt` from my `devDependencies` as well?

Comment: @ZackShapiro Yes. It's outdated, uninstall it. `npm uninstall --save-dev electron-prebuilt`.

Comment: Thanks for your help Andrew

Comment: Short for `npm uninstall --save-dev electron-prebuilt` is `npm r electron-prebuilt`. You don't need `--save-dev` when removing, only when saving

Comment: @Catalin In previous npm version the save-dev was required to save the package.json file after removing packages. You can edit if you'd like to update the answer.